# SQL Server - count of COLUMN X where COLUMN X has a letter in it

Tags: sql-server

In my database, I have a field called "recipient ID".  The "recipient ID" should be only numerical numbers.  To ensure only numerical numbers are in the "recipient ID" column, I want to do a count of how many records where the "recipient ID" has an alpha character in it.
  How do I do that?  (if patindex is used, how do I set the parameters ?)

Comment: Use ISNUMERIC or TRY_CAST functions

Comment: @Jan - Both of those would accept `1E5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are only interested in ASCII alphabetic characters then you can use the below.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable
WHERE ColumnX LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%'
```

You should compare with

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable
WHERE ColumnX LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

(the second one finds rows where the column contains any character that is not a digit)